# Differentiable function except at integers.

Tags: real-analysis

$f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function which is not differentiable only  at the integer points, then 
 a) f is bounded 
b) f is unbounded
c) f is uniformly continuous
d) f may not be uniformly continuous.

We can construct a periodic function which is bounded not differentiable only at integers.

Is it possible to construct unbounded function which is not differentiable at integer points??

Comment: What if you multiply your bounded function $f(x)$ by $x$?

Comment: how about $\{x\}\times \lfloor x \rfloor $ for an unbounded function not differentiable at integers, where $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x \rfloor$?

Comment: @saulspatz:  $xf(x)$ could be differentiable at $0$, no?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner It might be.  Hard to know without seeing the OP's example.  I was just suggesting a line of attack, not claiming this was an answer.

Comment: @saulspatz Replace $x$ by $x^2+1$ ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 
$$f(x)=(x^2+1)|\sin(\pi x)|$$

Answer (score 0):

If you think about how $|x|$ is differentiable except at $0$ you can see you need corners at all the integers.  One way on the positive part of the axis is to start from $0$ with a slope of $1$, then jump to a slope of $2$ at $x=1$, a slope of $3$ at $x=2$ and so on.  If you integrate this you find that at the naturals you have $f(x)=\frac 12x(x+1)$, which is unbounded.